# Remove out-of-view polygons in react-native-maps

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I am drawing thousands of polygons on my MapView that are coming from API based on the center of the map. But I only want to draw the polygons that are currently near the center and when the user moves the center away, the polygons that are no longer in view get removed from the memory.

How can I achieve this?